ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers
How can I resolve this?
Unfortunately does not let me upload full code. Need this to run in order for chatbot to work. Anyone know how to fix? Would be greatly appreciated if you have some time and are able to help by contacting, can send further code with zip via email thanks.
import nltk
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()
import json
import pickle

import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Dropout
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
import random

Result below:

ImportError: cannot import name 'SGD' from 'tensorflow.python.keras.optimizers'(C:\Users\Ali_B\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python312\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\optimizers.py)


I believe it should be just tensorflow.keras.optimizers without python bit.

In my instance this does not work as I have to include python otherwise I get a yellow underline. Unless if I have to import something?

I don't know what you mean. AFAIK there's no python module within Tensorflow Python package. Even if it underlines with yellow, does removing python resolve the issue?

No as I get this "File "c:\Users\Ali_B\Documents\ITMB\Final year\ACareers-app\training.py", line 73, in 
training = np.array(training)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence. The requested array has an inhomogeneous shape after 2 dimensions. The detected shape was (47, 2) + inhomogeneous part. What does this mean?

This error is not related to the import. It is talking about some array presumable in your data that is inhomogenous.

I have successfully executed the code in TensorFlow 2.17.1 .Please refer
gist with the code is attached for your reference.Let me know if you are still
facing the issue
